# Package caption Warning: The caption type was already set to `quadro' on input line 38

Tags: captions, listings, environments, minted

With the following minimal example, there are the nested environments code and `quadro`, where both use `captionsetup`. And when building the the example, I got the warning: `` Package caption Warning: The caption type was already set to `quadro' on input line 38.See the caption package documentation for explanation ``

I managed to fix it by replacing the line `\captionsetup[quadro]{skip=1mm}` by `\AtBeginEnvironment{quadro}{\captionsetup{skip=1mm}}`.

But I do not understand what is happening. Reading the documentation it says:

> The caption type was already set to ‘htypei’.
>   This warning informs you about mixed caption options. For example if you use a \captionsetup{type=table} or \captionof{table}{. . . } inside a figure environment,
>   this would result in using both option sets for that specific caption, the one for figure
>   (specified with \captionsetup[figure]{. . .}) and the one for table (specified with
>   \captionsetup[table]{. . . }) as well.
>   (You can suppress this warning by using the starred form \captionsetup*{type=. . .}.)
>   (See section 3.2: Setting options)

Why replacing `\captionsetup[quadro]{skip=1mm}` by `\AtBeginEnvironment{quadro}{\captionsetup{skip=1mm}}` fixes the warning?

```latex
\documentclass[
brazilian,brazil,
12pt, % Padrão UFSC para versão final
a4paper, % Padrão UFSC para versão final
twoside, % Impressão nos dois lados da folha
chapter=TITLE, % Título de capítulos em caixa alta
section=TITLE, % Título de seções em caixa alta
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat,chapter]{minted}

\newenvironment{code}{
  \captionsetup{type=listing}
}{}

\AtBeginEnvironment{code}{\setcounter{listing}{\value{lstlisting}}
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
}

\def\listofquadrosname{List of Frames}
\def\quadrosname{Frame}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=\quadrosname,within=chapter,listname=\listofquadrosname]{quadro}

\captionsetup[quadro]{skip=1mm}
% \AtBeginEnvironment{quadro}{\captionsetup{skip=1mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{quadro}[h]
\caption{Example}
    \begin{code}
    \caption{File}
    Something.
    \end{code}
\end{quadro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both newfloat  (see minted) and caption create new caption types.  Obviously the interaction of the three packages is complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `\begin{quadro}` the caption type is set to `quadro` and any options declared with `\captionsetup[quadro]{...}` will be applied.

At `\begin{code}` the caption type is set to `listings` (since `code` is defined that way) and any options declared with `\captionsetup[listings]{...}` will be applied.

If you put a `code` inside a `quadro` you end up with a mixture of both options, the ones declared with `\captionsetup[quadro]{...}` and the ones declared with `\captionsetup[listings]{...}`. As a result a caption inside a regular `code` looks different than a caption inside a `code` which is placed inside a `quadro`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{listing}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{quadro}
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\captionsetup[quadro]{font=it}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
\caption{Test}
\end{code}

\begin{quadro}
\begin{code}
\caption{Test}
\end{code}
\end{quadro}

\end{document}
```

Both captions look different although both are captions of `code`.

In most cases this is an unwanted effect and something the user doesn't want to get. All captions of `code` should be formatted the same way, at least that is the common expectation.

For this reason the `caption` package issue a warning if such mixture of options from different environments happens.

Now to the second part of the question:

If `\captionsetup[quadro]{...}` is not used the warning disappears. The `caption` package knows that `quadro` does not have any special options anymore, and therefore a caption inside `code` will be formatted the same way as a caption inside `code` placed inside `quadro`.

But what about this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{listing}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{quadro}
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
\caption{Test}
\end{code}

\begin{quadro}
\captionsetup{font=it}
\begin{code}
\caption{Test}
\end{code}
\end{quadro}

\end{document}
```

This code has exactly the same output as the one above, but no warning is issued here, why? Because in this case the option "font=it" was placed inside the environment explicitly by the user, so here the `caption` package assumes the user knows what he it doing.

Same with `\AtBeginEnvironment{quadro}{\captionsetup{font=it}}`. Since the `caption` packages does not know if `\captionsetup{font=it}` is part of a macro or not, it classifies this change as "explicit" (and not implicit) and therefore does not issue a warning.

I hope this answer makes it more clear why the `caption` package behaves this way. If there are any questions left, please don't hesitate to ask.